# Release the resource unit at the end of shift so that the agent can take a different one from the same pool in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a schedule for nurses (resource) at the hospital where from 3pm to 7pm I have 6 nurses available. During other hours the number varies from 3 to 5. As an example, I need a nurse to take the patient to CT room and leave him there for the procedure. I seize nurse and CT room in block "CTseize" (queue capacity =1). The issue is that when a patient enters the queue in the seize block at for example 6:50 pm, waits for his turn, while another patient is in CT room (so the nurse is available but CT room is not, and he waits to seize them both) and the time passes 7pm (end of shift - 5 nurses available instead of 6), then even when the CT room is free and it's his turn, the nurse is not seized (because the one he "booked" is no longer available, I guess). And even though there is another nurse available, he waits until 3pm the next day when there will be 6 available again, as if he was waiting for this 6th one. This causes long waiting times.

To sum up, it looks like when the number of resources decreases due to end of shift, but the agent entered the queue before the end of shift, he has "booked" a specific nurse from the pool and when it's his time and she's not available he waits until she's back, even though others are free and could take him to CT room.

How to release the resource at the end of shift so that the agent can take a different one from the same pool?

I found "On unit state change" in Actions of ResourcePool block. However, I have no idea how to code it.

Thanks!